# Splitting a string while keeping the delimiters except escaped ones (regex)

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

If I have a String which is delimited by a character, let's say this:

```
a-b-c
```

and I want to keep the delimiters, I can use look-behind and look-ahead to keep the delimiters themselves, like:

```
string.split("((?<=-)|(?=-))");
```

which results in

- `a`
- `-`
- `b`
- `-`
- `c`

Now, if one of the delimiters is escaped, like this:

```
a-b\-c
```

And I want to honor the escape, I figured out to use a regex like this:

```
((?<=-(?!(?<=\\-))) | (?=-(?!(?<=\\-))))
```

ergo

```
string.split("((?<=-(?!(?<=\\\\-)))|(?=-(?!(?<=\\\\-))))"):
```

Now, this works and results in:

- `a`
- `-`
- `b\-c`

(The backslash I'd later remove with `string.replace("\\", "");`, I haven't found a way to include that in the regex)

My Problem is one of understanding.
The way I understood it, the regex would be, in words,

`split ((if '-' is before (unless ('\-' is before))) or (if '-' is after (unless ('\-' is before))))`

Why shouldn't the last part be "unless `\` is before"? If '-' is after, that means we're between '\' and '-', so only `\` should be before, not `\\-`, but it doesn't work if I change the regex to reflect that like this:

```
((?<=-(?!(?<=\\-))) | (?=-(?!(?<=\\))))
```

Result: `a`, `-`, `b\`, `-c`

What is the reason for this? Where is my error in reasoning?

Comment: You know, there are also negative lookbehinds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why shouldn't the last part be "unless \ is before"?

In

```
(?=-(?!(?<=\\-)))) 
    ^here
```

cursor is after `-` so `"unless \ is before"` will always be false since we always have `-` before current position.

---

Maybe easier regex would be

`(?<=(?<!\\\\)-)|(?=(?<!\\\\)-)`

- `(?<=(?<!\\\\)-)` will check if we are after `-` that has no `\` before.
- `(?=(?<!\\\\)-)`will check if we are before `-` that has no `\` before.

Comment: Ah, I diddn't know ?= shifts the cursor, I'm still pretty new to regex. Also, your easier example looks way better, thanks!

Comment: @pemko BTW all [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanism are zero-width. It means that they can shift cursor when needed while checking their conditions, but after they exit cursor will be reset to position where it was before look-around started.

Answer (score 2):

While this does not really answer the question, this explains how lookarounds work.

Lookarounds are anchors: they do not consume text, but find a *position* in the input text. Your regex can be written in a much more simple manner:

```
(?<=-)(?<!\\-)|(?=-)(?<!\\)
```

You have all four lookarounds here: positive and negative lookbehind, positive and negative lookahead.

The full regex reads:

```
(?<=-)            # Find a position where what precedes is a dash
(?<!\\-)          # Find a position where what precedes is not \-
|                 # Or
(?=-)             # Find a position where what follows is a dash
(?<!\\)           # Find a position where what precedes is not a \
```

Note the term "position". Note that an anchor *will not* advance in the text at all.

Now, if we try and match that regex against `a-b\-c`:

```
# Step 1
# Input:    | a-b\-c|
# Position: |^      |
# Regex:    | (?<=-)(?<!\\-)|(?=-)(?<!\\)|
# Position: |^                           |
# No match, try other alternative
# Input:    | a-b\-c|
# Position: |^      |
# Regex:    |(?<=-)(?<!\\-)| (?=-)(?<!\\)|
# Position: |               ^            |
# No match, regex fails
# Advance one position in the input text and try again

# Step 2
# Input:    |a -b\-c|
# Position: | ^     |
# Regex:    | (?<=-)(?<!\\-)|(?=-)(?<!\\)|
# Position: |^                           |
# No match, try other alternative
# Input:    |a -b\-c|
# Position: | ^     |
# Regex:    |(?<=-)(?<!\\-)| (?=-)(?<!\\)|
# Position: |               ^            |
# Match: a "-" follows
# Input:    |a -b\-c|
# Position: | ^     |
# Regex:    |(?<=-)(?<!\\-)|(?=-) (?<!\\)|
# Position: |                    ^       |
# Match: what precedes is not a \
# Input:    |a -b\-c|
# Position: | ^     |
# Regex:    |(?<=-)(?<!\\-)|(?=-)(?<!\\) |
# Position: |                           ^|
# Regex is satisfied
```

Here is an alternative which does not use split and no lookarounds:

```
[a-z]+(\\-[a-z]+)*|-
```

You can use this regex in a `Pattern` and use a `Matcher`:

```
public static void main(final String... args)
{
    final Pattern pattern
        = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+(\\\\-[a-z]+)*|-");

    final Matcher m = pattern.matcher("a-b\\-c");
    while (m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: Your simplification of the regex is the one I like most because it's the easiest to understand. Thanks for your long explanation, much appreciated. I'd mark your answer as the correct one, but Pshemo did answer the question directly, so to be fair, it belongs to him. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: I don't mind ;) The essential part is that it works for you now ;)